# How to parse an unstructured csv file

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a csv file which looks like below,

```
Processname:;ABC Buying
ID:;31
Message Date:;08-02-2012

Receiver (code):;12345
Object code:


Location (code):;12345
Date;time
2012.02.08;00:00;0;0,00
2012.02.08;00:15;0;0,00
2012.02.08;00:30;0;0,00
2012.02.08;00:45;0;0,00
2012.02.08;01:00;0;0,00
2012.02.08;01:15;0;0,00
```

It can have 1 or more occurance of the above message, so let's say if it had 2 occurances, then the csv file would look like...

```
Processname:;ABC Buying
ID:;31
Message Date:;08-02-2012

Receiver (code):;12345
Object code:


Location (code):;12345
Date;time
2012.02.08;00:00;0;0,00
2012.02.08;00:15;0;0,00
2012.02.08;00:30;0;0,00
2012.02.08;00:45;0;0,00
2012.02.08;01:00;0;0,00
2012.02.08;01:15;0;0,00
Processname:;ABC Buying
ID:;41
Message Date:;08-02-2012

Receiver (code):;12345
Object code:


Location (code):;12345
Date;time
2012.02.08;00:00;0;17,00
2012.02.08;00:15;0;1,00
2012.02.08;00:30;0;15,00
2012.02.08;00:45;0;0,00
2012.02.08;01:00;0;0,00
2012.02.08;01:15;0;9,00
```

What would be the best approach to parse this csv file?

**Pseudo code of my approach...**

```
// Read the complete file
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

// Split the lines at the occurrence of "Processname:;ABC Buying" 
var blocks = lines.SplitAtTheOccuranceOf("Processname:;ABC Buying");

// The results will go to
var results = new List<Result>();

// Loop through the collection
foreach(var b in blocks)
{
     var result = new Result();

      foreach(var l in b.lines)
      {

           // read the first line and check it contains "Processname" if so, assign the value to result.ProcessName = 

           // read the 2nd line and check it contains "ID" if so, assign the value to result.ID

           // read the 3rd line and check it contains "Object Code" if so, assign the value to result.ObjectCode

           // Ignore string.empty

           // check for location (code), if so assign the value to result.LocationCode

           // Parse all the other rows by spliting with ';' the first part is date, 2nd part is time, 3rd part is value


       }
      results.Add(result);
}
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: That doesn't look like CSV to me.

Comment: CSVs are a 'relatively' structured document, which the Microsoft Jet Engine to do it for you. So its definitely custom code time! - Link to RFC for CSV's - http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Comment: For what its worth I'd probably describe this as "a text file with a complicated structure" since it is structured, its just that not all lines are the same. If its totally unstructured then code would have no chance at all pretty much. ;-)

Comment: This looks more like an LDIF structured format then CSV (although it is neither). Is your goal to turn it into a CSV format?

Comment: This is a file coming out from a Legacy system. I wish I had more control over the format. Unfortunately I'll have to process this with custom code, rather than some clever generic code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is have an strongly typed object to hold this data, and a parser that takes a string and breaks it up as separate items:

```
// Has no behaviour - only properties 
public class Record 
{    
    public string ID { get;set;}    
    // Other fields 
}

// ------------------

// Only has methods ... 
public class RecordParser 
{    
   private string content;    

   public RecordParser(string content)    
   {
      this.content = content;    
   }

   public IEnumerable<Record> SplitRecords()    
   {
      var list = new List<Record>();

      foreach(string section in this.content.Split(/* ... */))
      {
          var record = CreateRecordFromSection(section);

          list.Add(record);
      }

      return list;    
   }

   private static Record CreateRecordFromSection(string content)     
   {
      StringBuilder currentText = new StringBuilder(content);

      var record = new Record()
      {
          ID = SetId(currentText),
          ProcessName = SetProcessName(currentText),
          /* Set other properties **/
      };

      return record;    
   }

   /* Methods for specific behaviour **/
   /* Modify the StringBuilder after you have trimmed the content required from it */    
   private static string SetProcessName(StringBuilder content) { }    
   private static int SetID(StringBuilder content) { }

   /** Others **/ 
}
```

From reading [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882), Uncle Bob may offer another approach, which is more to your liking.

This approach prefers local variables over passing variables in and out of methods. The idea behind this is you quickly realise how much your class is moving data around internally. If you are declaring too many variables, it is an indication that too much is happening. It also prefers shorter methods over longer ones.

```
public class RecordParser
{
   private List<Record> records;
   private Record currentRecord;
   private string allContent;
   private string currentSection;

   public RecordParser(string content)
   {
      this.allContent = content;
   }

   public IEnumerable<Record> Split()
   {
      records = new List<Record>();

      foreach(string section in GetSections())
      {
          this.currentSection = section;
          this.currentRecord = new Record();

          ParseSection();

          records.Add(currentRecord);
      }

      return records;
   }

   private IEnumerable<string> GetSections()
   {
      // Split allContent as needed and return the string sections
   }

   private void ParseSection()
   {
      ParseId();
      ParseProcessName();
   }

   private void ParseId()
   {
      int id = // Get ID from 'currentRecord'
      currentRecord.ID = id;
   }

   private void ParseProcessName()
   {
      string processName = // Get ProcessNamefrom 'currentRecord'
      currentRecord.ProcessName = processName;
   }

   /** Add methods with no parameters and use local variables
}
```

This approach can take a while to get used to, as you aren't passing in and out variables, but it flows quite nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly this doesn't look like a CSV file to me. Secondly I'd just go for reading the entire file line by line. Create a new object when you get a line like "Processname:;ABC Buying" which looks like its the first line of your object. Then for each line parse it and modify your object with whatever info is on that line. When you reach another "Processname:;ABC Buying" then save the object you've been working on into your results list and create your new object.

Your question doesn't have enough specifics to go into any more detail on how to parse lines, etc. but the above is the approach I would use and I doubt you'll get much better. Its worth noting that this is pretty much what you have got except that rather than splitting the file into lines corresponding to each object I would jsut do that splitting as you go through.